# How do I create/access ~/.lein/profiles.clj?

Tags: clojure

I am very new to Clojure and am following Clojure for the Brave and True. One of the steps is to create ~/.lein/profiles.clj . I cannot find how I am supposed to do this so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I take it that you are a) on a Linux system and b) do not yet know your way around Linux.  Is that correct?

If so, there are a few things, you should know:

- Filenames beginning with a dot are hidden.  You can not see them in normal file listings.  All graphical filemanagers have a switch somewhere to show hidden files.  If you are typing in a terminal, you can use the `-a` option of the command `ls` to show them.  Compare the output of `ls ~` and `ls -a ~`on the command line.  You can usually get a command line if you start a "terminal" or "console" from menu.
- You can create directories on the command line with `mkdir`.  In this case you would call it like this: `mkdir ~/.lein` on the command line.
- You can then use one of the many, many text editors to create and edit the `profiles.clj` file.  For example, on the command line call `gedit ~/.lein/profiles.clj` to open a graphical editor.  It should be installed on most systems.  If you do not have a graphical user-interface, you could try the editor `nano` instead of `gedit`

If you are on a Windows box, all these instructions make no sense.  In that case, I cannot help you much as I have never run Clojure on Windows.

If you are already an experienced Linux user and I just misread your question, I beg your pardon for stating the obvious.

Comment: Your solution could be OSX as well, not just Linux

Comment: Apart from `gedit` (and maybe `nano`?) that is true.

Comment: `nano` should come with OSX.